# Open BootStrap Modal using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I have this modal and I want it to appear (pop up) automatically when the page finishes its load event.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" data-show>
    <div class="modal-header" style="background: #5cb85c;">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel" style="color: #fff;">HEADER TEXT</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p style="font-size: medium;">SOME TEXT HERE</p>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:right; padding-right:15px;">
        <button id="buttonEvent" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-
        color: #ec9c51; border-color: #ec9c51;" target="_blank">BUTTON TEXT
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I have a problem: I can't use jQuery and I need the Close Button to work properly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Au9tc/6310/ here is fiddle for you.

Comment: Why cannot you use jQuery? It is [required](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js) for Bootstrap.

Comment: I cannot use JQuery because we use a customized Magento Platform and the agency who built it disabled the JQuery to external use.